# Julia code optimization calculating decimal period

Tags: julia

Im trying to solve problem 417 in ProjetEuler. I wrote a code to optimize and calculate the procedure but its still far from enough.
I based my algorithem from the findings in this website https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DecimalExpansion.html

The only tasking part of the code is in the check function but no matter how I look at it the Time complexity shouldnt be big enough for my PC to handle. and yet it is painfuly slow.
I added more process's to help and it seemed to speed up the runtime by no less than double, but its not enough.

```
using Distributed;
@everywhere using SharedArrays
addprocs()
function createDict(limit)
   a = Dict(2 => true);
   for i = 0:(floor(log2(limit))+1)
       for j = 0:13
           if ((2^i * 5^j) <= limit)
               get!(a,(2^i * 5^j),true)
           end
       end
   end
   return a;
end
arr = createDict(10^6)

@everywhere function check(x)
   mem = []
   for i = 1:x
       power = i-1;
       num = (BigInt(10)^power) % x
       push!(mem,num)
       for j = 1:(length(mem)-1)
           (mem[j] == num ) && return (i-j);
       end    
   end
end

@everywhere function test(limit,arr)
    a = SharedArray{Int16}(limit)
    @sync @distributed for i=3:limit
        flag = false;
        flag = get(arr,i,false)
        (flag == false) && (a[i] = check(i))
    end
    return sum(a);
end
@elapsed test(10^6,arr)
```

the createDict just holds all the fractions that are finite in arr up to certain limit(I overshoot it just in case, its done once)
check function returns the decimal cycle length and test is my main.

It also seems that the workload of the cpu drops from 100% to almost nothing after couple of minutes and yet it runs. (and isnt stuck, i can interrupt)

Comment: Could you please clarify what is your question exactly? If it is to make your algorithm more efficient implementation wise - then the answer is that using this algorithm you will not be able to solve this problem efficiently no matter what implementation or what programming language you use. Note for example that even calculating `BigInt(10)^power` where power is of order of `100_000_000` takes over 1 second and you want to do this calculation millions of times.

Comment: The thing is even at `limit = 10^4` the runtime is about 194 [sec] in my machine so I thought that Im doing something bad with the way Im coding. Thanks for answering, I'll look into other algorithems about dealing with high powers since far as I know its essential here because numerical algorithems may be more accurate but they always got roundup errors as they approximate the result. 
Though there is one question that Id like to get an answer to, Why does `1//5 == 1/5` gives false and `1//2 == 1/2` is true? both are finite

Comment: I changed the `BigInt(10)^power` to `pow *= 10`  in the loop so that `num = po %x` while initializing it at 1, The speed up was small, got `174 [sec]` instead of `194 [sec]` with `limit = 10^4`.
There most be something else that is slowing it down though I cant seem to figure what

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that in my opinion the key to the solution of this problem is located elsewhere (and following the SO policy I do not want to comment on it), the way to rewrite `check` to improve its speed is e.g.:

```
function check(x)
    mem = Dict{Int,Int}()
    num = 1
    for i = 1:x
        haskey(mem, num) && return i - mem[num]
        mem[num] = i
        num = 10num % x
    end
end
```

Comment: Totally understandable, I wouldn't even want to hear the answer if its algorithm wise different, well at least not until I solved it haha. anyway thanks for the help again.
I want to ask if you dont mind why is there such a big performance difference with the check functions? complexity wise mine does `n(n-1)` loops and yours `n` though the inner loop in my code is just bool check. I used `@time` on both and saw that mine allocates way more memory even though the array/dict size is the same, even more so I tried to configure the array again as `mem = {Int,1}()` and the allocation just went up

Comment: I will refer to the code you have posted in the question about the differences. There are the following things that cause it: 1) `mem = []` creates an array of `Any` which is type unstable; not only it uses more memory, but also is slower. 2) By doing `%` on each step of the iteration I can use `Int` not `BigInt`, which again - saves memory and execution time. 3) By doing `BigInt(10)^power` you do exponentiation in each iteration, which is expensive. I just do multiplication which is much cheaper. Finally 4) `Dict` lookup makes my algorithm O(n), and your is O(n^2), which is a huge difference.

Comment: If you post your updated code I can have a look at it and comment on the differences.